# How does websphere manage session in cluster environment?

Tags: session, websphere, cluster-computing

How does websphere manage session in cluster environment? Does it necessary to manage session by ourselves in our application?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can do session replication in WAS ND.
There are several approaches depends on version on how it handles.
 Safest and slowest way is to store sessions in database.
See here for [details](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cprs_sess.html)